# Even spacing vertically and horizontally with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to create even spacing between items inside a flex element? I tried using `align-content: space-around` but it seems to have no effect. Is this possible? If not, is there another way I can achieve this even if I don't use flex?

In example below, I have even spacing horizontally, but not vertically. To make it clear, I want whatever spacing is horizontally to be the same vertically .

Example code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: 19%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7vp3uyf/2/

Comment: **No**...not unless you specify the margins.

Comment: Use the grid instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want *equal spacing* in both axes use margins.

If you want *even spacing* in each axis, consider this:

- The browser provides default width and height settings.
- Horizontally, you're working with `width: 100%`.
- But vertically, you're working with `height: auto`.

So you can't achieve even spacing across both axes, because the available space is different.

In particular, `justify-content: space-between` can work because there's free space on the main axis. But `align-content: space-around` can't work because there's no free space in the cross axis.

---

Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default.

This is how they meet their design requirement, which is to stack vertically.

> [**9.4.1 Block formatting
>   contexts**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting)
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.

This behavior, however, does not extend to height.

By default, most elements are the height of their content (`height: auto`).

Unlike with width, you need to specify a height if you want extra space.

Therefore, keep these two things in mind:

- unless you want full width, you need to define the width of a block element
- unless you want content height, you need to define the height of an element

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh; /* new */
}

.item {
  width: 19%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

body { margin: 0; } /* remove default margins */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex instead of width in item class 
e.g:flex: 1 1 19%; (shorthand for flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 19%)

```
.item {
  flex: 1 1 19%;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e7vp3uyf/26/ the 4px forces the boxes to fall in new line if screen gets small enough.

Comment: can you try margin-bottom in percentage e.g(margin-bottom: 1%;) in item class in your previous code e.g(.item {width: 19%;margin-bottom: 1%;})

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e7vp3uyf/35/ That makes it always have 4 columns in first 2 rows and 2 columns in last row. And also the last 2 columns in the last row are 50% width now.

Comment: yes I understand actually I talk about the your code.  you can add this code in item class      .item {width:19%; margin-bottom: 1%;}

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same amount of `margin-bottom` within your first row of elements.
You can do it like these,

```
element:nth-child(1),
element:nth-child(2)..to..(5){
  margin-bottom: same amount of margin you put in right;
}
```

If anything not working, then comment below...